# Tooltip for tag seems irrelevant

Tags: feature-request, tooltips

I asked a question about [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) and [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) not so long ago, and I saw this tooltip:

[image]

While I understand the need it fills, I find it a bit irrelevant since:

- It already include a specific tag ([c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23))
- I'm not that far from the silver [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex)

Is there a way to make it conditional?